# Cloud Chamber Help Needed!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos, leptons

I was inspired by [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gt3Ad5_Z5IA) to attempt to create a cloud chamber without dry ice (it's very challenging to get where I live) and I have had limited success so far. This is what the design looks like:

[image]

A heat sink filled with the coolant gel sits on the bottom (cooled to about -18 degrees celsius). There is about 13 cm from the top of the base to the top of the actual chamber, where a piece of felt soaked in 91% isopropyl alcohol sits. The felt is attached to a layer of aluminum tape that fully covers the top of the chamber. The two sections are completely blocked off from each other. The aluminum tape itself was able to stop water from leaking into the bottom chamber when I poured water into the top. However, I decided to throw the plastic bag in there so as to not damage the adhesive. I fill the bag with water that is around 50 degrees celsius. I've run quite a few tests now to no avail. Any advice on how I could get this to work? Is it even possible to get this to work?

Comment: there is this similar demonstration, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoLgIGgbxT4 , but it needs a radiation source. I suspect cosmic rays where you have your effort will not show up.